# New Relic Wayne on Heroku Apps

Tags: php, heroku, deployment, newrelic

While trying to Add New Relic Wayne to my Heroku App, I keep getting this warning on the deployment , How to Solve this ?

```
 WARNING: New Relic detected, but no suitable extension available
```

and this warning on the new relic page

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like there is a mismatch between the version of PHP detected during installation and the New Relic agent capability. If you are attempting to use PHP 7.0 this could be the problem.

The PHP 7.0 version of the New Relic PHP Agent has not been released yet due to the extensives differences between 7.0 and the previous versions. It is still undergoing testing but should be released soon. No firm date has been set.

Comment: Thank you very much ,,, this is the case ... what do you advice me to do ?